# Android Studio standalone sdk manager doesn't start

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10, android-studio, android-sdk

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 (64 bit) and Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit). I have Android Studio installed in windows and the sdk folder is located at

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

I have also installed Android Studio in ubuntu and I changed the sdk location in the ubuntu installation to

```
/mnt/C Drive/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Android/sdk
```

Android Studio recognized all the platforms and tools installed (I actually have packages downloaded, hence trying to use a single sdk path and save disk space). But when I tried to open the standalone sdk manager nothing happened. So I copied all the files from

```
/root/Android/Sdk
```

to

```
/mnt/C Drive/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Android/sdk
```

and didn't replace any existing file. I noticed that some files from ubuntu had the same name as the corresponding files in windows but were ubuntu executables. For example the files in windows had .exe or .bat extension while the ones in ubuntu had no extension even though both had the same name. Opening some files with gedit and comparing the same files with .bat extension showed different file contents. So I figured copying all the files that belong to ubuntu installation without replacing any files from windows installation should fix the problem.

Now, when I start the standalone sdk manager, the 'Starting SDK Manager' popup shows up but nothing happens after that. Is there anything else I'm missing here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Oracle Java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Make sure you first remove Open JDK (if installed) to avoid conflict >>> Check java Version >>> Terminal >> java -version

Comment: I have Java 8 installed and it's running fine. I don't think that's the cause of this problem.